# How are Environment Variables handled when executing exec(tcsh) in perl in a jenkins client?

Tags: perl, jenkins-pipeline, execution, tcsh

I am integrating an EDA development environment into Jenkins pipeline. I am trying to emulate how a real user would experience changes to the EDA framework on multiple sites. The Frameworks is a complex Perl environment which sets a large list of environment variables for project specific tool configuration. On a interactive shell session the control flow return control to the user by executing exec "tcsh"; However, when executing on a Jenkins client, the new shell with updated variables are not getting set.

## setup.pl

```
// Manipulation of $ENV{} here
print "Running perl\n";
$cmdstring = " -c \"$Option{command}\"";
exec "$ENV{SHELL}${cmdstring}" || "tcsh${cmdstring}";
```

## run_client.csh

```
#!/usr/local/bin/tcsh 
# Wrapper to execute in tcsh with .cshrc environment vars
echo home ~/
echo pid $$
./setup.pl  $1
echo home ~/
echo pid $$
```

## groovy script:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('login') {
            steps {
                sh "$HOME/run_client.csh ${params.EDAWORKSPACE}"

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am looking for a way to return control flow after the tcsh is executed.

Current output is:

```
1. home /home/me/
2. pid 6768
3. Running perl
4. home /home/me/
5. pid 6768
6. [no change to env]
```

Comment: Each process gets a copy of its parent's environment. Changes to a process's environment only changes *that process's* environment. As you've seen, it definitely doesn't modify it's great-great-grantparent's. You will need to somehow output data or code that you later use or execute in the shell whose environment you want to change.